# Java Android Native thread issues

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I have one thread that does lot of time consuming tasks. The tasks are being done in the native part in c++.  I would like to cancel the operation that is being done in the native, the code for that is place. I can reset everything.

```
mWorker =  new WorkerThread("Worker thread");
mWorker.start();
//From Main thread:- Interrupting
mWorker.interrupt();
if(mWorker.isInterrupted()) {
    Log.i(MOD_TAG, "Worker thread is interupptedd!!! ");
}

//Worker thread
public class WorkerThread extends Thread implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            Looper.prepare();
            mHandler = new WorkerHandler();

            Looper.loop();
        }

        class WorkerHandler extends Handler {
            @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                try {
                    switch(msg.what) {            
                        //do something native code     
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even if the workerthread is interrupted I cannot send any message to the worker thread while the worker thread is doing processing. Can I do something to post a message to workerthread or do something else that could let me call a native method within the same thread.

Comment: Do you want to cancel the whole looper (it will not process more messages/tasks) or just one message/task?

Comment: I want to cancel only 1 task which has been started by one of the messages.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I don't understand what that Handler is doing inside the Thread. Once you call `loop()` within the run, that call will block until the looper is stopped via quit() or quitSafely(). The call is basically just a loop which reaps a queue for messages. Your check for interrupt will never happen.

I would recommend something like this. If you want your code to be managed by a handler you would do something like:

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("NativeHandler");
handlerThread.start();
Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()) {

  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
     someObject.callNativeLongRunningFuction();
  }
};
```

However interrupt still won't do anything because the looper only handles one message at a time. So if it is stuck handling `callNativeLongRunningFunction()`, that is not going to help you really either. If you want to have interrupt stop the ongoing execution of the jni call, the I don't think this approach will work at all with the given information. Interrupt in java only sets a flag and when there is a call to wait(), it will throw an exception when that flag is checked and also set.  But for a jni call there isn't a call to wait(), the java stack is  sort of blocked but it is not in the middle of a wait() either. So unless you check interrupted within the native runtime, that function will continue to run. Overall I am guessing this probably would not be what you really want.

If that is so, I would recommend something like this instead.

```
public class NativeThreadTask {

   public native void start();

   public native boolean isRunning();

   public native boolean cancel(); 

}
```

Inside the native implementation of that class, you would then use a pThread to call your native long running function. Start and Cancel would manipulate that pThread which would run the expensive function in a separate thread. Using pthread_cancel you can interrupt that pthread instance too. This moves the long operation off your thread and out of your runtime, while still allowing you to control when the pthread interrupt mechanism is invoked but over the jni bridge. If you don't even want to interrupt and if the long running native call is iterating over a large amount of data, then it might be worthwhile to have cancel() simply change bool that is evaluated within each iteration of the native function's loop.

So with the given example you could probably do something like this.

```
NativeThread nativeThread = new NativeThread();
Handler handler = new Handler() {

   public void handleMessage(Message message) {
      NativeThread nativeThread = (NativeThread)message.obj;
      switch(message.what) {
          case 0:
             if (!nativeThread.isRunning()) {
                  nativeThread.start();
             }
             break;
          case 1:
             if (nativeThread.isRunning()) {
                 nativeThread.cancel();
             }
             break;
          default:
          }
   }

};
```